# Iphone, always set a Facebook app's audience to Public

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am with a Facebook app. When the user initially login with his Facebook id he can set the audience as Public, Private, and Only Me. My question is, is it is possible to set the audience as public always Programmatically?

Comment: I guess you are missing `Programatically` magic word. Please update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's done on Facebook. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps => your app => Settings => Auth Dialog and change `Default Activity Privacy` there.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** for the correct answer: Go to *App Details* => *Configure App Center Permissions* and change *Default Activity Privacy* there.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to use -

```
        FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
        loginManager.defaultAudience = FBSDKDefaultAudienceEveryone;
```