# set default audience as public instead of friends, with fb api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am working on a webapp using facebook php sdk v5. I would like the highlighted dropdown below to be set/preselected to **public** instead of **friends** ( seems to be a default behaviour ).

[image: default audience - public]

There is [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866423/how-to-set-default-audience-when-facebook-app-login?#answer-30274688) to a similar question but the syntax is in JavaScript. I tried to simulate the syntax in php with the code below

```
$params = array('scope' => 'publish_actions', 'default_audience' => 'everyone');
```

Facebook quickly throws an error 'sorry, something went wrong'. My guess is, it did not agree with the 'default_audience' parameter.

I see a possible solution in an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446937/iphone-always-set-a-facebook-apps-audience-to-public#answer-23436085) , but unfortunately the suggested solution seems outdated, since I could not find the setting below in  my app-settings.

```
 App Details => Configure App Center Permissions => Default Activity Privacy
```

---

Is it even allowed or possible to achieve this ? Any tips or resource are welcome. TIA.

Comment: No, it is not possible any more to specify a default value.

Comment: @CBroe thank you. Now that I know, I can move on.